# PHP Post_method hacking

Tags: php, curl, post

I ran into the snippet online
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-PHP-hated-by-so-many-developers
when I was doing some research about PHP, and I simply have no idea how the codes work.

Can anyone kindly explain what happens in the snippet and how one can log in without knowing the password?? or just give me some relevant articles to read. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why does your screenshot (→why?) omit the (albeit slim) explanation part from said article? And why is your question title so shallow?

Comment: Also, side note, this is not a very good example of how to check for passwords. What's next, saving the passwords in the database in cleartext format? Look into password hashing @ http://php.net/password - if you learn it right the first time, you won't have to worry about it later :)

Comment: ive never seen `strcmp` used like that in any real project

Comment: @mario sorry for that cuz i have little knowledge about this topic and didnt really know how to ask. I add the link to the article but there isn't much explanation.

Answer (score 2):

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

> Returns ... `0` if they [strings] are equal.

So, by the snippet logic, you should compare `0` to `0` in the end. But when you send `password[]=wrong`, you actually send an array, forcing `strcmp` to throw a `warning`, completely bypassing the function call and perceive the condition as `true`

You should always use strict comparison, just in case. So in the snippet above it would be enough to compare strictly by type and value (with `===`):

```
if(strcmp($POST['password'], "sekret") === 0)
```

In this case `password[]=wrong` would not work anymore.